# Find duplicate parameters in command line on bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, parameters

I am searching for a way to see if a command line parameter has a duplicate or not in bash.

In other words, when I do `./imp.sh matches matches matches target` my program has to send an error because matches was repeated three times. (`./imp.sh` is the name of the program).

I can search for the correct number of parameters but I can't see weather every parameter is unique.

For seeing the correct number of parameters, I do:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
 echo "Incorrect number of parameters"
 exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting *exactly* three unique parameters, it's simple enough to check the possibilities exhaustive:

```
if [ $# -ne 4 ]; then
    ...
elif [ "$1" = "$2" ] || [ "$1" = "$3" ] || [ "$2" = "$3" ]; then
    echo "First three arguments must be unique"
    exit 1
fi
```

If there are an arbitrary number of elements, use the keys of an associative array as a set.

```
declare -A unique

for arg in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do
    if [[ -v unique[$arg] ]]; then
        echo "Duplicate arg $arg"
        exit 1
    fi
    unique[$arg]=  # The value doesn't matter; the empty string is as good as any
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Could you say what ```"${@:1:$#-1}"``` means and also ```-v``` checks what?

Comment: `"${@:1:$#-1}"` is a way to iterate over all but the last positional argument; it takes a "slice" of `$@` from the first element to the next-to-last one.  `-v` tests if a variable exists; with an indexed array name, it checks if that particular element exists (analogous to `arg in unique` in Python, for example).

Comment: I should note that while the first example is straight-up POSIX, both the `-v` operator and associative arrays are `bash` extensions.

Comment: Thank you. I need to write this in bash. So no problem with shell

Comment: So the answer you gave me works perfectly with directories but it doesn't work with files. The first three arguments are directories and last argument of my program is a file. So if I do ```./imp.sh matches/ target/ bin/ matches```, it send me an error like ```matches: Is a directory```. Could you please explain why this is hapenning?

Comment: I just replace ```for arg in "${@:1:$#-1}"; do``` with ```for arg in "${@}"; do``` and it works just fine but (as I ask it always) is this a good way to this?

Comment: It's fine, if it does what you want. I only did it because the example in your question made it seem like the last argument was fundamentally different from the preceding arguments.